# Unknown UI Addon

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have an unidentifiable addon on my default WOW UI (screenshot below)
I have uninstalled all addons (except MoveAnything).

This seems to have occurred recently when trying to get a PS3 controller to work using WOWMapper (which didn't work), I cannot identify the addon (in green) so therefore cannot remove it.

It appears in all my toons on all servers (even new toons). It controls character movements.

[image: Please identify the green object]

Comment: I'm not sure Gaming.SE is the best place to ask about mods.  Can you list the files in your `World of Warcraft\Interface\AddOns\` directory?

Comment: This might not even be an Addon in the WoW scope -- it could be another program with it's own UI that's running on top of WoW. Check your process list in Windows to see what else is running.

Comment: Thx for looking, it's been solved now anyway

Comment: Then write a answer what is was...

Answer (score 2):

For completeness here the answer: What you see there is the Move Pad which allows movement with the mouse instead of the keyboard (in addition to the normal movement you can do with the mouse itself). You can (de)activate it under the Accessibility options in the game menu:

[image]